# Where is the event handlers wired up when using AutoEventWireup?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autoeventwireup

I am trying to track down a bug in a web application, that seems to relate to AutoEventWireup being used. When and how is the events wired up when using AutoEventWireup ?

I know that it happens runtime, but exactly in which framework class/method ? ([I am hoping that I will be able to step through the framework code](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, your .aspx page is parsed, and the result is turned into a class. The wireup is done in this generated class.

Comment: John, that is what I thought, but looking at the generated class in Reflector reveals that this is not the case.

Comment: Is this a Web Site Project, or a Web Application Project?